# Select statement combining two different columns

Tags: mysql

My Question:-

Write a SELECT statement that returns list of customers and products they bought on sale (discount). You result set must include LastName, FirstName, OrderDate, ProductName, ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, and Quantity 
Use aliases for the tables.
Sort the final result set by LastName, OrderDate, and ProductName.

My ERD:-[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hslb1.png)

My Answer:-

SELECT LastName, FirstName, OrderDate, ProductName, 
    ItemPrice, DiscountAmount, Quantity

```
    FROM Customers, Orders, OrderItems, Products
    WHERE 
    Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
    AND
    Orders.OrderID = OrderItems. OrderID
    AND
    OrderItems.ProductID = Products.ProductID
    AND DiscountAmount > 0
    ORDER BY LastName, OrderDate, ProductName
```

It is working perfectly well..but I was just wondering if there is a better way to do it?
Any suggestions!!?

Comment: I suggest using explicit inner joins.

Comment: You did not “Use aliases for the tables”.

Comment: yes I was just wondering where to use them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible improvement would be to use explicit joins instead of the implicit join syntax that were deprecated in 1992, and also use table aliases to make the query more readable:

```
SELECT 
  c.LastName, 
  c.FirstName, 
  o.OrderDate, 
  p.ProductName, 
  oi.ItemPrice, 
  oi.DiscountAmount, 
  oi.Quantity
FROM 
  Customers c
INNER JOIN 
  Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN 
  OrderItems oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID
INNER JOIN 
  Products p ON oi.ProductID = p.ProductID
WHERE 
  oi.DiscountAmount > 0
ORDER BY 
  c.LastName, 
  o.OrderDate, 
  p.ProductName;
```

Note that these changes doesn't affect the performance or result of the query.

It might be that you are supposed to use aggregate functions too and sum up the discount amount and/or count the quantity too - the question isn't that clear.

Comment: Yes I think this makes it much more readable and looks cleaner as well ...mine worked but was very childish I think..this is better ..thanks:)